# How to create tsvector_update_trigger on Non-character type data in PostgreSQL with gin?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

How can I create a tsvector update trigger on non-character data type in PostgreSQL with gin for full-text search support?

For instance, having the case of a `posts` table that has:

- `title` (varchar)
- `text` (varchar)
- `status` (enum ['published', 'draft']
- `likes` (integer)

I've created an index column:

```
ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD COLUMN "posts_full_text" TSVECTOR';

UPDATE "posts" SET "posts_full_text" = to_tsvector('english', title || ' ' || text || ' ' || status || ' ' || likes);

CREATE INDEX np_search_idx ON "posts" USING gin("posts_full_text");
```

Then tried to create trigger to update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_posts_tsvector BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON posts FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
tsvector_update_trigger("posts", 'pg_catalog.english', title, text, status, likes);
```

The statement above throws an error saying that `status` and `likes` columns are non character types.

Trying to cast won't work neither throwing an error that says that method signature doesn't match:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_posts_tsvector BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON posts FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
tsvector_update_trigger("posts", 'pg_catalog.english', title, text, status::VARCHAR, likes::VARCHAR);
```

So, by this way is impossible to index non char variant columns until a casting strategy is achieved.

Answer (score 3):

The way to achieve this is by creating a stored function where we can cast and then pass it to `to_tsvector()` instead to `tsvector_update_trigger()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_posts_tsvector() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new."posts" :=
     setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.text,'')), 'B') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.status::TEXT,'')), 'B') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.likes::TEXT,'')), 'B');
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(we can omit `setweight` wrapping method and just use `to_tsvector` directly)

And then bind that function to our updating trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER np_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "posts" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_posts_tsvector();
```

Hope this will be useful for someone.